# Translation of "better than I thought it would be"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, comparison

> The show was better than I thought it would be.

How can we translate this into German? I think

> (a) Die Aufführung war besser als ich dachte.

already captures the meaning of the sentence, but it leaves out the part "it would be" at the end. How can we insert that part? Something like

> (b) Die Aufführung war besser als ich dachte sie wäre.

doesn't sound right.

Comment: A comma shall be used if _als_ introduces a subordinate clause of comparison:
_Die Aufführung war besser, als ich erwartet hatte._

No comma is used if _als_ just compares component parts of a sentence:
_Die Aufführung war besser als erwartet._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Die Aufführung war besser als erwartet.
```

oder

```
Die Aufführung war besser als zuvor gedacht.
```

Comment: "Besser als zuvor gedacht" würde ich nicht verwenden. "Besser als erwartet" wird sicher am häufigsten gebraucht.

Comment: @MartinSchwehla: Weder ist die Frage was am häufigsten gebraucht wird, noch was Du persönlich bevorzugst. Wenn Du etwas bevorzugst, dann solltest Du es begründen - ansonsten ist das nur eine Befindlichkeitsmeldung und auf Twitter vielleicht besser aufgehoben. (Bitte nicht persönlich nehmen, aber so ist die Stoßrichtung der SE-Plattformen).

Comment: @ user unknown — Vielleicht ist es doch relevant, welche Formulierungen einzelne User verwenden, und zumindest für nicht deutschsprachige User ganz sicher relevant, was besonders häufig gebraucht wird. Das ist nicht notwendigerweise, was ich am häufigsten verwende, sondern was ich am häufigsten höre und lese. Was native speaker den anderen auf jeden Fall voraus haben, ist, dass ihnen bestimmte Wendungen und Formulierungen "richtiger" vorkommen und "stimmiger" im Ohr klingen als andere, weil sie die Sprache ständig verwenden. (Fortsetzung folgt)

Comment: @ user unknown Teil 2 — Und konkret: der Zuschauer weiß nicht, wie die Aufführung ursprünglich "gedacht" war, sondern nur, wie er gedacht hat, dass sie sein würde, und das ist ein Unterschied. "Zuvor gedacht" ist ein Pleonasmus. Eine geläufige, allerdings umgangssprachliche Formulierung mit "dachte" wäre: "Die Aufführung war besser als ich dachte".

Comment: @MartinSchwehla: "Nachdem mir der Experte für das brechtsche Theater die Zusammenhänge zwischen Chor und den illuminierten Rhomben erklärt hatte, revidierte ich mein Urteil und sage nun, die Aufführung war besser als gedacht". Ein sicher arg konstruiertes Beispiel, aber es zeigt, dass das gedacht von einem zuvor gedacht durchaus verschieden sein kann, also dass man noch während der Aufführung und eine Zeit danach auf die eine Weise gedacht hat, aber jetzt anders denkt - nicht aber zuvor.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of "show" this is about, a somewhat literal translation of the last part works, too:

> Die Show war besser als ich dachte, dass sie (es) sein wird. *(don't stop at the comma)*

Comment: Für welche Shows wäre das denn nicht geeignet?

Comment: Warum "wird" statt "würde"?

Comment: @Em1: Z. B. amerikanische Sitcoms. *The Big Bang Theory* wird im Englischen als Show bezeichnet, im Deutschen als Serie. (*Aufführung* würde hier natürlich auch nicht passen.)

Comment: Do we need a comma before "als", as per @Loong's comment? "A comma shall be used if *als* introduces a subordinate clause of comparison"

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Gehört denn einer hin? Ich schrieb es so nieder, wie ich es gesagt hätte.

Comment: Noch einmal darüber sinniert: Zumindest mündlich wahrscheinlich nicht. Ich könnte jetzt natürlich behaupten, dass ich nur anregen wollte, dass Du diesen Unterschied zum Englischen erläuterst;)

Answer (score 0):

Es fällt auf, dass im Englischen in Vergleichsätzen der Vergleichsteil gerne als vollständiger Satz  formuliert wird, während das für das Deutsche völlig untypisch ist.

Englisch: He's better than I am.

Deutsch: Er ist besser als ich.

Es wäre also nicht richtig, hier "Er ist besser als ich bin/ als ich es bin" zu übersetzen.

"Die Show war besser als ich dachte" ist die idiomatisch richtige Übersetzung.
Würde man hier nach "dachte" noch etwas anflicken, wäre das Englisch mit deutschen 
Wörtern, aber kein Deutsch.

Answer (score -1):

'Thought' here means 'expected', so your translation should use the verb *erwarten*, not *denken*.

> Es war etwas Besseres als das, was ich erwartete.

[erwarten](http://www.dict.cc/?s=erwarten)